# Why the password key has a value of "foo" from Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails book Chapter 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, railstutorial.org

I'm currently following Michael Hartl's ROR book to create a web application. The following is the code from [Chapter 7](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up).

**Listing 7.21: test/integration/users_signup_test.rb**

```
 require 'test_helper'

    class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

      test "invalid signup information" do
        get signup_path
        assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
          post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                                   email: "user@invalid",
                                   password:              "foo",
                                   password_confirmation: "bar" }
        end
        assert_template 'users/new'
      end
    end
```

It is to test the validity of a user signup form. I'm a bit confused about why the values for **name**, **email**, **password** and **password_confirmation** are filled this way? (meaning, for example, why the value of **email** is **user@invalid**; why the **password's** value is **foo**?)

Thank you very much and I'm looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing invalid signup information to make sure a user is not created. You're performing a http post request to the users create action and you're sending the data in that users hash. `Foo` and `bar` are arbitrarily chosen values mainly significant because they don't match as the password and confirmation are required to.

Answer (score 3):

I am agree with **toddmetheny** answer 
in fact you can modify the test as you want for example

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path   # go to the sign up path 
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do   # This assertion is checking that "username" should not be inserted in User table if the password and password_confirmation is not same   
      post users_path, user: { name:  "username",
                               email: "user@invalid",
                               password:              "123456",
                               password_confirmation: "123" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'  # This assertion is checking that after invalid password user should go to users/new template 
  end
end
```

Hope that i make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

As per [Chapter 7 from Ruby-on-Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up), Micheal is trying to explain in that section how there should be **validations** on our signup page and make it clear to our application of what to accept from user and what NOT to accept from user.

Now your question is why the **email** is filled as **user@invalid**. This is because we want to **test the validations that we have applied on signup page**. According to which an email is only valid if the format is something like user@invalid.com; this makes the application understand the valid format submission.

Similarly for **password : foo**, you can see that we have two values that are supposed to match which are **password and password_confirmation**. And in the above code, they both **don't match** so again as I explained it makes the application understand that this is not a valid submission.

And lastly, as you can see the code, these values are under

```
test "invalid signup information" do
```

which makes us understand that show message invalid signup information if the information is as below, i.e.:

```
name:  "",
email: "user@invalid",
password:              "foo",
password_confirmation: "bar"
```

All of these are non acceptable information.